# How to handle weight conversions

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently facing an issue converting between metrics and imperial weights when working with gym equipment. So here in the UK we work with weights in Kilo's where they can increment by 1.25, but overseas i.e. US the weights are measured in pounds and can increment by 0.5.

Handling this isn't an issue, the issue arises when I use the formula to convert between kilo, pounds and vice versa the values are way off. For example a standard UK barbell is 20KG and a US barbell is 45lbs, but when i use the Measurement class to convert it will spit out 44.0925. I already know to convert kilo to pounds you have to multiply it by `2.205` but this is just one example and other values are just as way off.

I've already thought of some other possible solutions one being having an array of possible values in kilos and another that will hold a possible values in pounds but this feels hacky and also wouldn't work since users can input their values into a textfield, which may be an invalid value.

Just curious to see/know if anyone has tackled switching between weight conversion before especially with gym equipment.

Comment: May I cynically guess that 44.09 is rounded up so it looks more impressive, lifting 45 instead of 44 pounds :)? If it is so simply then you can always round upwards to the next integer, if not then you are going to need some translation table for gym weights.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Nope I don't really want to start rounding values up or down because then I may get inconsistencies. A translation table is looking more and more like the solution I might have to implement tbh...

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by keeping what user has selected option is like it is pound or kg

```
enum WeightUnitConverted:String {
    case kg =  "kg"
    case pounds = "pound"
    case none = ""

}


var weightUnitConvertedValue: WeightUnitConverted =  WeightUnitConverted.kg
```

You have to change this `weightUnitConvertedValue`  whenever the user changes the  measurement type. before that you can convert the values

like  this I have `MVVM`

```
    self.viewModel.updateWeightUnit(string: self.weightUnit[selectedRow]) // Like kg or pound, So self.viewModel.weightUnit = "kg"

    self.viewModel.updateWeight(string: self.viewModel.convertWeightValues())
    self.txtWeight.text = self.viewModel.weight
    self.viewModel.weightUnitConvertedValue = WeightEntryViewModel.WeightUnitConverted(rawValue: self.viewModel.weightUnit)!
```

Here is `convertWeightValues()`

```
func convertWeightValues() -> String {
    // We need to convert to pounds 
    if weightUnit.lowercased() == "pound" && weightUnitConvertedValue == .kg {
        let punds = convertKGtoPounds()
        return punds > 0 ? punds.asNumber : ""
    } else if  weightUnit.lowercased() == "kg" && weightUnitConvertedValue == .pounds {
                // We need to convert to KG 

        let kg = convertPoundsToKG()
        return kg > 0 ? kg.asNumber : ""
    }
    return self.weight //No need to change so return current weight 

}
```

I know this is a bit confusing for you to implement someone's code Please ask me whatever query you have

Comment: I know all of this, you're still not understanding my question. In the gym a bar is 20kg but in pounds is 45lbs. If i input 20kg into your function it will spit out 44lbs which is wrong since it's off by 1lbs...

Comment: @Tunds There is no way to do that unless some third party has done researched on it and provides apis or sample codes, you have to manually do this , Like you may create the array of available weights and return the nearest value of converted value. You also may create API that provides a latest weight units